# 'Uncaught (in Promise) TypeError' error in console after recaptcha with emailjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, recaptcha

this one's a bit weird so I'll do my best to sum it up well.

I'm creating a react app, and I am implementing emailjs for submitting form data. I have it set up to use recaptcha, and the form process is **fill out form** -> **click submit button** -> **submit recaptcha** -> **form submits**.

This seems simple enough, but when the recaptcha submits I get the `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError` console error. This normally comes with a warning and a stack trace in my experience, something like `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object is not iterable` or the like, but this doesn't give anything. It says it originates from anchor:1, but when I click on it to view the file, it doesn't take me to the file, just toggles the non-existent stack trace.

I've spent some time looking around, but I am not seeing anyone else have errors quite like this, as every other one I've seen gives the follow up information properly.

I'll paste the code below, if anyone could give some guidance I'd appreciate it.

```
export function Form(){
  const form = useRef();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    'fname': '',
    'lname': '',
    'email': '',
    'message': '',
  });

  const[captcha, showCaptcha] = useState(false);

  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    showCaptcha(true);
  }
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  };

  const sendEmail = (e, captchaValue) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const params = {
      'g-recaptcha-response': captchaValue,
      formData
    };
    emailjs.send('service_id', 'template_id', params, 'public_key')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          e.target.reset();
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(params);
          console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return(
    <>
      
        <form className="d-flex flex-column" ref={form} onSubmit={submitForm}>
          <label htmlFor="fname">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onChange={handleChange} />

          <label htmlFor="lname">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" onChange={handleChange} />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />

          <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="30" onChange={handleChange} ></textarea>

          <fieldset className="d-flex flex-row mt-3">
            <input type="submit" className="mx-2" />
            <input type="reset" className="mx-2" />
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        {!captcha ? (<></>) : (<div className="px-3 mt-3"><ReCAPTCHA theme='dark' sitekey='sitekey' onChange={sendEmail}/></div>) }
      </>
  );
}
```

I censored the keys of course, but if I missed anything I'd also appreciate a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when you load Recaptcha on an unsupported domain. You can add domains or manage your keys here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin